# Has any country ever voluntarily admitted to genocide?

Tags: genocide

I am curious if any country has ever admitted to genocide of their own volition without being diplomatically pressured to do so, as a matter of losing a war, sanctions or other not-so-voluntary means?

E.g. the public admittance (for which I am not sure what the proper legal format is) in Germany over the Holocaust as well as other Nazi war crimes didn't even start until about 1970 when Willy Brandt went to the Warsaw Ghetto.  In addition to the long term issue of the Turkish denial of the Armenian genocide, a less conspicuous is the avoidance of Serbia (and its big brother, Russia) to acknowledge the genocide in the Bosnian war of the 1990s.  Other examples include the massacres of the Natives in the Americas etc etc, none of which have, I believe and correct me if wrong, have been acknowledged as "genocide".

Comment: Republican Rome; Mongols under Genghis and descendants. Timurlane. Assyrian conquest of Israel. The list isnearly  endless. Have you done any research?

Comment: This is my research

Comment: Ha! At least that it an honest answer by an OP.

Comment: why would anyone be doing research the old fashioned way by digging through microfiche and such in the age of QA forums on the interwebs where you can just get an answer??

Comment: Official Apology by Government of Canada to Aboriginal Peoples of Canada for *Cultural Genocide*: http://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/government-apology-to-former-students-of-indian-residential-schools/ and https://www.aadnc-aandc.gc.ca/eng/1100100015644/1100100015649

Comment: Because on the interwebs people have an agenda *and* are anonymous, so you can find all kinds of crazy, untrue affirmations (like that Canada did apologize, for example) without any kind of support. People writting books *have* an agenda, too, but are publicly known and cannot make that kind of affirmations without some kind of documental proof that they must make available to the public. Remember that neither science nor truth are democratics (the number of supporters of an idea is not a measure of how valid such an idea is).

Comment: Just to pick an example, try to ask in any Turkish speaking forum why Turkey has not yet apologized for the Armenian Genocide and see what happens...

Comment: But are interested in *mine*, or Pieter Geerkens'?

Comment: there is a difference asking in a themed, biased environment ("Turkish speaking") vs. a neutral one like this is supposed to be ("history", without biased connotations) -- duuh

Comment: What would be the motivation for admitting to a crime against humanity? Why would any country do this?

Comment: Let's keep this civil please.

Comment: why is this off topic ?

Comment: @Mark Pour encourager les autres?

Answer (score 6):

A Modern example of public apology:

Official Apology by Government of Canada to Aboriginal Peoples of Canada for Cultural Genocide:

1. [The Canadian Encyclopedia](http://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/government-apology-to-former-students-of-indian-residential-schools/)
2. [Government of Canada website](https://www.aadnc-aandc.gc.ca/eng/1100100015644/1100100015649)

Comment: I think Australia did one of those, too

Answer (score 4):

> German authorities are moving toward officially recognizing as a "genocide" the colonial-era crackdown in Namibia by German troops more than a century ago in which more than 65,000 ethnic Hereros were killed.
>   http://www.foxnews.com/world/2015/07/10/germany-moves-toward-recognizing-as-genocide-colonial-era-crackdown-against/
>
> The Auswärtige Amt declared ... : "The war of extermination in Namibia from 1904 to 1908 was a crime against humanity and genocide." 
>   ...
>   Chancellor, President and the German Bundestag avoided a recognition of the genocide in the past. Presumably also for fear of demands of reparation that are being raised for years from the Namibian side.
>   http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/namibia-massaker-bundesregierung-spricht-von-voelkermord-a-1043117.html